# For loop only calculates first line

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to construct a for loop that solves for a list of variables in a data set.
However, once I run it, the code only seems to calculate the first variable.

```
for (t in 1:nTest){
m = DataTest$Item[t]
u = DataTest$User[t]
Sorted = sort(ItemSim[,m], decreasing = T,index.return=TRUE)
MostSim = Sorted$ix[1:N]
Wgts = ItemSim[MostSim,m]
DataTest$CosineItem = (t(Wgts) %*% UM.Item[MostSim,u])/sum(Wgts)
DataTest$CosineItem}
DataTest$CosineItem
```

Any help with this issue is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you needd `DataTest$CosineItem[t]`

Comment: That solves it. Thank you for you patience.

Answer (score 2):

The `CosineItem` column is getting updated/replacing from each loop.  If we are updating a particular row, then use the index

```
for (t in 1:nTest){
   m <- DataTest$Item[t]
   u <- DataTest$User[t]
   Sorted <- sort(ItemSim[,m], decreasing = T,index.return=TRUE)
   MostSim <- Sorted$ix[1:N]
   Wgts <- ItemSim[MostSim,m]
   DataTest$CosineItem[t] <- (t(Wgts) %*% UM.Item[MostSim,u])/sum(Wgts)
}
```